# Regex with PowerShell won't work with /n (newline)

Tags: powershell, replace, find, ps

For some reason, newline characters will not work with my regex.

Here's the first part of the PowerShell script. This piece of code is used to get a set of markdown files. For testing purposes, I'm only using the first file.

The code then gets the content inside the file.

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Will\Desktop\ProjectTemp'

$filelist = ls $path -filter *.md -recurse

[string[]]$currentfile_path = $filelist[0].FullName

$currentfile_data = Get-Content $currentfile_path
```

This is the problematic code. It works fine anywhere else, but PowerShell will not find the matched so that they can be replaced. Specifically, I have found that the newline characters will not work. Nothing I have tried will work.

```
$currentfile_data -Replace '([ \t]*)\| (.*) \| (.*) \| (.*) \|\r\n[ \t]*\| .* \| .* \| .* \|\r\n[ \t]*\| (.*) \| (.*) \| (.*) \|','$1<table>\n$1\t<tr align="center" valign="middle">\n$1\t\t<th>$2</th>\n$1\t\t<th>$3</th>\n$1\t\t<th>$4</th>\n$1\t</tr>\n$1\t<tr align="center" valign="middle">\n$1\t\t<td>$5</td>\n$1\t\t<td>$6</td>\n$1\t\t<td>$7</td>\n$1\t</tr>\n$1</table>'
```

This is meant to find the regex:
`'([ \t]*)\| (.*) \| (.*) \| (.*) \|\r\n[ \t]*\| .* \| .* \| .* \|\r\n[ \t]*\| (.*) \| (.*) \| (.*) \|'`

and replace it with:

```
$1<table>\n$1\t<tr align="center" valign="middle">\n$1\t\t<th>$2</th>\n$1\t\t<th>$3</th>\n$1\t\t<th>$4</th>\n$1\t</tr>\n$1\t<tr align="center" valign="middle">\n$1\t\t<td>$5</td>\n$1\t\t<td>$6</td>\n$1\t\t<td>$7</td>\n$1\t</tr>\n$1</table>'
```

What the input and output should look like:

```
| th1 | th2 | th3 |
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| td1 | td2 | td3 |
```

```
<table>
    <tr align="center" valign="middle">
        <th>th1</th>
        <th>th2</th>
        <th>th3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" valign="middle">
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way this can be fixed? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [`ConvertFrom-Markdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown?view=powershell-7.3) is built-in in PowerShell Core. Do you really need regex?

Comment: Maybe try `\r?\n` and I would not use `.*` between all those `|`, rather use negation ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5AFPa/2)).

Comment: See [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##nZLbTsMwDIbv@xRWFGkdYkLbOEijGw@yMJI1Zq2UhcmEw0XevbgZgxYmENw49pc/dvK3u4cXpMcKnWsaWT4RoQ/3tcM7a4KBOYgIoRpDGycpTiFmEWajGfQis2CTziadZZ24zjJJuMFXbjRY5UtQ4fZkqCLky5Ui5SNX8Fup6Eb5/VHe@9iCn4r@mb9Mk4N0550zJW7Zi9YCLcdFMGuHC@0516EIBMbVGz/XomQRkhbwfCDb2lqHWhzUrb5aaDkpztq1D6fH4HkXck7/H2y53QW3sF/h5TF41YWfgzlLzxfszbd/ZPTuFuT7b30KXf@GTfMG)

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

```bash
$currentfile_data = Get-Content -Raw $currentfile_path
```

`-Raw` ensures that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) reads the iput file *as a whole*, as a *single, typically multi-line* string, which ensures that the subsequent `-replace` operation can perform matching *across lines*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$currentfile_data = Get-Content $currentfile_path`

This saves an *array* of the *lines* from the input file in variable `$currentfile_data`, because [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) by default streams the target file's lines *one by one*.

> `$currentfile_data -Replace '...'`

This makes the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator act on *each element* of the array stored in `$currentfile_data`, i.e. on *each line* of the original file rather than *across lines*.

---

**A [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) alternative:**

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, PowerShell (Core) 7+ ships with the **[`ConvertFrom-Markdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown)** cmdlet, which **can directly transform your input file to HTML** (albeit not in the exact same format):

```bash
(@'
| th1 | th2 | th3 |
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| td1 | td2 | td3 |
'@ | ConvertFrom-Markdown).Html
```

Output:

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align: center;">th1</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">th2</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">th3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">td1</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">td2</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">td3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```